# How to delete Expired Accesstokens From DB

Tags: php, sql, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php
include'config.php';
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$thispage = $PHP_SELF;
$num = mysql_num_rows($items);
$per_page = 100;
$start = @$_GET['start'];
if(empty($start)) $start = 0;
?>
<center>
<?php
if($start+$per_page<$num){
?>
[<a href="<?php print("$thispage?start=".max(0,$start+$per_page)); ?>">Delete 100 Tokens</a>]
<?php
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT $start,$per_page");
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$token = $row[access_token];
$userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);print($userData[name]).'<br/>';
if(!$userData[name]){
mysql_query("
DELETE FROM
table
WHERE
access_token='" . mysql_real_escape_string($token) . "'
");
}
}
}
?>
```

i Have this Code For Deleting Expired Access tokens From database  but when i execute it It delete all access tokens at once Which include Valid and Expired Both Tokens Please Help Me How to Delete Only Expired Sorry For Ban English.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: `if(!$userData['name'])` note quotes around name

Comment: Not Fixed by using Quotes around Name

Answer (score 0):

try after change

```
if(!$userData[name]){
```

to

```
if(!$userData['name']){
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the expiry of each token, if the token expiry is older than the current date delete it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

Response

```
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": 000000000000000, 
        "application": "Social Cafe", 
        "expires_at": 1352419328, 
        "is_valid": true, 
        "issued_at": 1347235328, 
        "scopes": [
            "email", 
            "publish_actions"
        ], 
        "user_id": 1207059
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Graph.facebook.com` to `graph.facebook.me` solved the issue for me.